# Make a bootable USB stick for MacBook Air, with wifi drivers?

Tags: drivers, wireless, live-usb, macbook-air

I was able to make a bootable USB stick that I could use on a MacBook Air, except that it did not have the necessary driver for the wifi hardware, meaning I was unable to connect to the network.

I did look at the steps on '[Creating a bootable USB Stick](https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-create-a-usb-stick-on-macos)', but it didn't indicate any steps to add extra drivers.

The [instructions](https://askubuntu.com/questions/862703/macbook-air-1-1-wireless-broadcom-driver-not-working) given for installing the drivers are, in a booted Ubuntu to run:

```
sudo apt-get purge bcmwl-kernel-source
sudo apt-get install firmware-b43-installer
```

Though, I have no network connection to be able to do this and even then will this stick through reboots?

Comment: Please edit your post to include the output of `lspci -knn`. Once we have that info, either Chili555 or Pilot6 should be able to help you :)

Comment: I am not sure how that would make a difference of making a bootable USB stick from MacOS, if I already know the drivers I need? Are you suggesting Ubuntu would add this driver to a future ISO? I was looking for a generic formula for adding any additional drivers would be useful. I'll do it anyhow when I get home, since I don't have the USB stick with me.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem. Use a Thunderbolt to Ethernet adapter, it is detected out of the box (no connection needed). Then you can install the wlan drivers.